# Nested json to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

```
{
    "resources":{
        "har":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/har",
        "screenshot":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/screenshot",
        "video":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/video",
        "filmstrip":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/filmstrip",
        "report_pdf":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf",
        "report_pdf_full":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf?full=1",
        "pagespeed":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed",
        "pagespeed_files":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed-files",
        "yslow":"https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/yslow"
    },
    "error":"",
    "results":{
        "report_url":"https://gtmetrix.com/reports/gtmetrix.com/Cz0AQOjf",
        "html_load_time":"87",
        "html_bytes":"3395",
        "page_load_time":"522",
        "page_bytes":"89229",
        "page_elements":"16",
        "pagespeed_score":"95",
        "yslow_score":"98"
    },
    "state":"completed"
}
```

I would like to convert nested json to a csv file.
I am receiving the json from Rest API.
The fields in csv should look like following.
resources.har,resources.screenshot,results.report_url etc
I am new to Python and JSON so would love to get some help

Comment: Can you please show us a precise output example?

Comment: And also show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you provide your expected output in CSV format?

Comment: I want to get columns like resources.har,resources.screenshot,results.report_url and so on.... in my csv file and corresponding values that are shown above

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) to load the data into pandas as a `DataFrame` and then [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) will save the file as a csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {
    'resources': {'har': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/har', 'screenshot': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/screenshot', 'video': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/video', 'filmstrip': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/filmstrip', 'report_pdf': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf', 'report_pdf_full': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf?full=1', 'pagespeed': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed', 'pagespeed_files': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed-files', 'yslow': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/yslow'}, 
    'error': '',
    'results': {'report_url': 'https://gtmetrix.com/reports/gtmetrix.com/Cz0AQOjf', 'html_load_time': '87', 'html_bytes': '3395', 'page_load_time': '522', 'page_bytes': '89229', 'page_elements': '16', 'pagespeed_score': '95', 'yslow_score': '98'}, 
    'state': 'completed'
}

json_normalize(data, sep='_').to_csv("filename.csv")
```

the contents of the csv file would look as follows:

```
,error,state,resources_har,resources_screenshot,resources_video,resources_filmstrip,resources_report_pdf,resources_report_pdf_full,resources_pagespeed,resources_pagespeed_files,resources_yslow,results_report_url,results_html_load_time,results_html_bytes,results_page_load_time,results_page_bytes,results_page_elements,results_pagespeed_score,results_yslow_score
0,,completed,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/har,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/screenshot,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/video,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/filmstrip,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf?full=1,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed-files,https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/yslow,https://gtmetrix.com/reports/gtmetrix.com/Cz0AQOjf,87,3395,522,89229,16,95,98
```

If you don't want to use pandas you can write the conversion by hand and use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

data = {
    'resources': {'har': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/har', 'screenshot': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/screenshot', 'video': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/video', 'filmstrip': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/filmstrip', 'report_pdf': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf', 'report_pdf_full': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/report-pdf?full=1', 'pagespeed': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed', 'pagespeed_files': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/pagespeed-files', 'yslow': 'https://gtmetrix.com/api/0.1/test/TtGJTbkv/yslow'}, 
    'error': '',
    'results': {'report_url': 'https://gtmetrix.com/reports/gtmetrix.com/Cz0AQOjf', 'html_load_time': '87', 'html_bytes': '3395', 'page_load_time': '522', 'page_bytes': '89229', 'page_elements': '16', 'pagespeed_score': '95', 'yslow_score': '98'}, 
    'state': 'completed'
}

data_out = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for ik, iv in v.items():
            data_out[f'{k}_{ik}'] = iv
    else:
        data_out[k] = iv

with open("filename.txt", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=list(data_out))
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(data_out)
```

Comment: can you tell me how to append in json_normalize?

Comment: You don’t, take a look at the documentation. Or just append after it’s loaded.

Comment: there is a error in above code in line  data_out[f'{k}_{ik}'] = iv

Comment: If you're not on Python 3.6+ you need to use str.format not f-strings

Comment: i dont know about both the things.Can you give me the above code in python 2 please

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be the pandas json package.
Lets say you have `sample_json_df`. All that is needed is to:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
result = json_normalize(sample_json_df)
result.head()
```

which gives the desired output.

Comment: where are we creating csv file and where are we taking json file input?

Comment: You are not creating a csv in the above code, you are creating a pandas dataframe stored in your memory. You can output this dataframe to csv using the `pd.to_csv()` method which you can read about here, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html. You might also like to take a look at the `json.normalize` documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html